# Questions regarding a optimizing a slow query (SQL included)

Tags: query-optimization, django-orm, database-optimization

```
SELECT DISTINCT "myapp_profile"."user_id", "myapp_profile"."name", 
  "myapp_profile"."age", "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username", 
  "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", 
  "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", 
  "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" 
FROM "myapp_profile" 
INNER JOIN "auth_user" ON ("myapp_profile"."user_id" = "auth_user"."id") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "myapp_siterel" ON ("myapp_profile"."user_id" = "myapp_siterel"."profile_id") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "django_site" ON ("myapp_siterel"."site_id" = "django_site"."id") 
WHERE ("auth_user"."is_superuser" = false 
AND "auth_user"."is_staff" = false 
AND ("django_site"."id" IS NULL OR "django_site"."id" IN (15, 16))) 
ORDER BY "myapp_profile"."user_id" 
DESC LIMIT 100
```

The above query takes about 100 seconds to run with 2 million users/profiles. I'm no DBA and our DBAs are looking at the situation to see what can be done, but since I'll likely never get to see what changes (assuming it happens at the DB level), I'm curious how you could optimized this query. It obviously needs to happen a ton faster than it is happening, like on the order of 5 seconds or less. If there is no way to optimize the SQL, is there an index or indexes you could add/change to make the query it quicker, or is there anything something else I'm overlooking?

Postgres 9 is the DB, and Django's ORM is where this query came from.

### Query Plan

```
Limit (cost=1374.35..1383.10 rows=100 width=106)
-> Unique (cost=1374.35..1391.24 rows=193 width=106)
-> Sort (cost=1374.35..1374.83 rows=193 width=106)
Sort Key: myapp_profile.user_id, myapp_profile.name, myapp_profile.age, auth_user.username, auth_user.first_name, auth_user.last_name, auth_user.email, auth_user.password, auth_user.is_staff, auth_user.is_active, auth_user.is_superuser, auth_user.last_login, auth_user.date_joined
-> Nested Loop (cost=453.99..1367.02 rows=193 width=106)
-> Hash Left Join (cost=453.99..1302.53 rows=193 width=49)
Hash Cond: (myapp_siterel.site_id = django_site.id)
Filter: ((django_site.id IS NULL) OR (django_site.id = ANY ('{10080,10053}'::integer[])))
-> Hash Left Join (cost=448.50..1053.27 rows=15001 width=53)
Hash Cond: (myapp_profile.user_id = myapp_siterel.profile_id)
-> Seq Scan on myapp_profile (cost=0.00..286.01 rows=15001 width=49)
-> Hash (cost=261.00..261.00 rows=15000 width=8)
-> Seq Scan on myapp_siterel (cost=0.00..261.00 rows=15000 width=8)
-> Hash (cost=3.55..3.55 rows=155 width=4)
-> Seq Scan on django_site (cost=0.00..3.55 rows=155 width=4)
-> Index Scan using auth_user_pkey on auth_user (cost=0.00..0.32 rows=1 width=57)
Index Cond: (auth_user.id = myapp_profile.user_id)
Filter: ((NOT auth_user.is_superuser) AND (NOT auth_user.is_staff))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not so familiar with postgres, so I'm not sure how good it's query optimiser is, but it looks like everything you have in the where clause could instead be join conditions, although I'd hope postgres is clever enough to work that out for itself, however if it's not then it's going to fetch all your 2 million users with related records in the other 3 tables and then filter that using your where.

The indexes already mentioned should also work for you if they don't already exist.  Again i'm more an MSSQL person but does postgres not have any statistics profile or query plan you can see?

Something along these lines

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    "myapp_profile"."user_id",
    "myapp_profile"."name", 
    "myapp_profile"."age",
    "auth_user"."id",
    "auth_user"."username", 
    "auth_user"."first_name",
    "auth_user"."last_name",
    "auth_user"."email", 
    "auth_user"."password",
    "auth_user"."is_staff",
    "auth_user"."is_active", 
    "auth_user"."is_superuser",
    "auth_user"."last_login",
    "auth_user"."date_joined" 
FROM "myapp_profile" 
    INNER JOIN "auth_user"
        ON ("myapp_profile"."user_id" = "auth_user"."id") 
        AND "auth_user"."is_superuser" = false
        AND "auth_user"."is_staff" = false 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "myapp_siterel"
        ON ("myapp_profile"."user_id" = "myapp_siterel"."profile_id") 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "django_site"
        ON ("myapp_siterel"."site_id" = "django_site"."id") 
        AND ("django_site"."id" IS NULL OR "django_site"."id" IN (15, 16))
ORDER BY "myapp_profile"."user_id" DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Also, do you need the distinct?  That'll also slow it down somewhat.

Comment: Very interesting. I have a feeling that's what's happening (given the fact that a limited by 100 query is taking so long). How would you write it to do what you speak of, in the case that Postgres is so naive?

Comment: I've added a query plan. Thanks, I'm going to take a look at your SQL.

Comment: be interested to see if the plan changes when running my version.

Comment: I'm unable to get a custom query to cooperate with Django's admin queryset requirements, but I ran the query manually, and got this: https://gist.github.com/d3ab71a22a144a56955d

Comment: Oops, this is the correct URL (accidentally made that one private): https://gist.github.com/1058975

Comment: Was it any faster?  That updated query plan is using more indexed by the looks of it, which is a good thing!

Comment: yes, it was 2 times as fast (just finished checking that). Thanks! I've learned a lot from this (also learning that seq scans == evil when not needed to achieve the same result. (too bad I can't use it as-is in Django's admin, finding out whether our DBA can do something at the DB level or not)

Comment: the speedup was lost when applied to a large dataset :( but removing DISTINCT from the query and dealing with duplicates Python-side seemed to fix the entire thing (minus the fact that DISTINCT in Python when dealing with the Django admin is a pain in the ass)

Comment: Ah yes, DISTINCT will slow down any DB query usually, since it has to get the dataset and then weed out the dups.  Well done for sorting it though. :)

Answer (score 1):

for basics:

make sure all the user id fields are indexed.

also looks like you would do well with an index on is_supervisor, and is_staff

Comment: can you post the explain plan?

Answer (score 1):

there's never a straight forward silver-bullet solution for query optimization, however, the obvious steps is to index columns you're searching on, in your case, that's:

```
"auth_user"."is_superuser"
"auth_user"."is_staff"
"django_site"."id"
"myapp_profile"."user_id"
```